# Unable to connect to postgres with typeorm

Tags: javascript, postgresql, docker, nestjs, typeorm

I have this `docker-compose.infra.yaml` config:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports: 
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_USERNAME: postgres

networks:
    default:
        external:
            name: learning
```

along with this `docke-compose.yaml` config:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  web_app:
    container_name: web_app
    image: node:14
    entrypoint:
      ["/bin/sh", "-c", "yarn start:dev --preserveWatchOutput"]
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    ports:
      - 3001:3000

networks:
  default:
      external:
          name: learning
```

I am starting it as:

`start.infra.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

docker network create learning

docker-compose -f docker-compose.infra.yaml start
```

`start.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

docker network create learning

docker-compose up
```

`make start`:

```
.PHONY: start
start:
    @./start-infra.sh
    @./start.sh
```

My db is up and running, I can connect to it using pgAdmin using credentials like these:

[image]

The password is `postgres`. And here's my nest.js code:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TasksModule,
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'postgres',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 5432,
      username: 'postgres',
      password: 'postgres',
      database: 'postgres',
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      synchronize: true,
    }),
    AuthModule,
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And while it looks to me like I'm doing everything correctly, I must be missing smth, since I am unable to connect to the db from the code. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
host: 'localhost',
```

should be:

```
host: 'db',
```

From within the container, the postgres DNS name is the same as the service name, `db`, not `localhost`. By default, each container has it's own isolated networking namespace, including a private `localhost` that only talks the container, not to other containers, and not to your external host.

Comment: Damn I would've never thought of this. Thank you! So it's called `db` only within the docker network now right? That's why localhost works with pgadmin?

Comment: @AlexIronside publishing a port creates a forward from the host into the container, so pgadmin running on your host accesses localhost which is that port forward. The host a different network namespace from each container, so each has a separate localhost.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!